Two Spheres - Total Volume as they move away
We have two spheres (radius 10) precisely inside each other as to appear as one.
How far should we move the center of one (with respect to the other's center) so that the total volume of the new shape is 1.25x one of the orinigal spheres?
Not exactly this one  as we're trynig to solve for a given distance instead
s1 = ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
s2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 10)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
Volume[RegionUnion[s1, s2]]

RegionPlot3D[{s1, s2}, PlotPoints -> 50]

Assume we want something like this:
Solve[Volume[
   RegionUnion[
    ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}], 
    ImplicitRegion[(x - R)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}]]] == 
  1.25 * ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, 
     z}], R, Reals]



Isn't the answer already there? Which part are you having difficulty?

Try it...! Doesn't work

I tried of course:  https://i.sstatic.net/kEL6w4Eb.png

Sure, why doesn't this same thing work?  Solve[{Volume[
RegionUnion[
ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}],
ImplicitRegion[(x - R)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}]]] ==
1.25 * ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}]}, R]

You've missed a Volume in right hand side of the equation.

You can use Ball, for example

Edit I think the following answered OP's question correctly, but I don't understand why MMA's answer that the volume v12 is not symmetric under $a\mapsto -a$.
Is it a bug or due to some (hidden) region orientation convention?

You can use a parameter $a$ in specifying ImplicitRegion:
ClearAll["Global`*"];
s1 = ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
s2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - a)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
AbsoluteTiming[v12 = Volume[RegionUnion[s1, s2]]]


v1 = Volume[s1]
(* (4000 \[Pi])/3 *)

ans = NSolve[v12 == 1.25*v1, a]
(*. {{a -> -36.2008}, {a -> 3.36509}, {a -> 32.8357}} *)

RegionPlot3D[{s1, s2 /. ans[[2]]}, PlotPoints -> 50]



How do the other 2 solutions make sense? .... how can 32.8 work if the diamater is 20 max?

Yeah, I have a related question and thus edited my answer. The volume is correct throughout the range $0\leq a \leq 20$. Probably MMA forgot to check positivity  of the volume somewhere.

Also:  if we introduce 3 variables, a, b, c (move x,y,z) in 3 directions, then i asume cartesian distance would still be a NET 3.36 away, hence the radial distance away from that center will still be coordinates which total distance will be 3.36 from them [square of the differentia's squared] hence there will be infinite coordinate points

Not very surprising. The region related functions are indeed buggy at least for now…

I think there are some bugs in Volume when applied to ImplicitRegions. I will ask this to SE as another question.

This is a cubic equation with 3 possible solutions. This is not an MMA bug. The other 2 simply do not apply to our physical, I plotted it and we can see the other 2 roots fine

@Steve237 I see what you mean. I am just wondering why Volume answered a formula which can be negative.

Because one of the 3 roots of the cubic equation is negative.   The Volume is not concerned with that. After all it is just solving that cubic equation.  we needed to put the limit of 0<a<20 on it

You are absolutely right. What I want to say is : even if $a=-10$, the MMA function Volume should return positive result. Please check https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/309211/volumes-of-union-of-implicit-regions
