Volumes of Union of (Implicit) Regions
This question arises from my previous answer to Two Spheres - Total Volume as they move away .
Consider two balls of the same size, centered at $(0,0,0)$ and $(a,0,0)$.
ClearAll["Global`*"];
b1 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10];
b2 = Ball[{a, 0, 0}, 10];
AbsoluteTiming[b12 = Volume[RegionUnion[b1, b2]]]


s1 = ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
s2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - a)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
AbsoluteTiming[v12 = Volume[RegionUnion[s1, s2]]]


Plot[{b12, v12}, {a, -50, 50}]


Question

Why volume v12 is not symmetric under $a\mapsto -a$?
Why the answers v12 and b12 totally ignore the fact that the volumes become constant for $|a|\geq 20$?

(I wonder if it is not safe to use parameters in Region related functions.)

Edit

In version 14.1, when we add GenerateConditions -> All

s1 = ImplicitRegion[(x)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
s2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - a)^2 + (y)^2 + (z)^2 <= 100, {x, y, z}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 v12 = Volume[RegionUnion[s1, s2], GenerateConditions -> All]]

we get

Original

I test the code in variety versions and only 11.3 get the right result. It must be a bug.



very instructive

The functions are as expected, e.g.
b1 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10];
bv[t_] := Ball[{t, 0, 0}, 10];
r[t_] := RegionUnion[b1, bv[t]];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{b1, bv[p]}, PlotLabel -> Volume[r[p]]], {p, 0, 30}]

Plot[Volume[r[x]], {x, -50, 50}]
FunctionExpand[Volume[r[t]]]
Table[{j, Volume[r[j]]}, {j, -25., 25.}] // Grid


-25.    8377.58
-24.    8377.58
-23.    8377.58
-22.    8377.58
-21.    8377.58
-20.    8377.58
-19.    8362.13
-18.    8316.84
-17.    8243.28
-16.    8143.01
-15.    8017.61
-14.    7868.64
-13.    7697.69
-12.    7506.31
-11.    7296.09
-10.    7068.58
-9. 6825.37
-8. 6568.02
-7. 6298.11
-6. 6017.2
-5. 5726.86
-4. 5428.67
-3. 5124.2
-2. 4815.01
-1. 4502.69
0.  (4000 \[Pi])/3
1.  4502.69
2.  4815.01
3.  5124.2
4.  5428.67
5.  5726.86
6.  6017.2
7.  6298.11
8.  6568.02
9.  6825.37
10. 7068.58
11. 7296.09
12. 7506.31
13. 7697.69
14. 7868.64
15. 8017.61
16. 8143.01
17. 8243.28
18. 8316.84
19. 8362.13
20. 8377.58
21. 8377.58
22. 8377.58
23. 8377.58
24. 8377.58
25. 8377.58

Update
Just to support @cvgmt answer (which I have voted for):
Volume[r[a], GenerateConditions -> All]



Thank you. I understand that the Volume of Region works as expected if the region is specified with explicit numeric values. But the region parameter contains a variable, then the problem occurs.  In fact, FunctionExpand[Volume[r[t]]] gives you (\[Pi](1200 t^2-t^4+16000 Sqrt[t^2]))/(12 Sqrt[t^2]), which does not approaches constant, which is easily seen by its graph.

I think, when Volume is called in Plot or Table  in your code,  the variable t is always given some numeric value, and that's why the result looks correct.

@A.Kato yes I put the function expand to illustrate “flaw” in just using parameter. The ImplicitRegion issue is a separate matter. I just posted to start discussion and hope you and other  users will provide better answers.

In Update, the second condition $\sqrt{a^2}\leq 0$ looks weird.

@A.Kato yes, really should be a==0. Tried to rectify with Assumptions but no effect.
